# Is there a simple way to check if a value is one of a number of other values in an if statement?

Tags: c#

Currently I have the code:

```
        if(Settings.Trk2 == 20 || Settings.Trk2 == 50)
        {
            await ReviewAppAsync(Settings.Trk2);
        }
```

If I want to add more checks is there a simpler way I can do this without checking against Settings.Trk2 each time.

Comment: List.contains(Settings.Tkr2) or better binary Search if list is too long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by the below ways

```
        var values = new []{20,50,35};
        if(values.Contains(Settings.Trk2)){
           //..
        }
```

or

```
        var values = new []{20,50,35};
        if(values.Any(v=>v==Settings.Trk2)){
                //...
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Basically you can try sth like this :

```
int[] valuesToCheck = new int[] { 20, 50, 60 ...};
if (valuesToCheck.Contains(Settings.Trk2))
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Linq`

assume `Settings.Trk2 = 20`

```
var valuesToCheck = new List<int> { 20, 40, 50};

if(valuesToCheck.Any(x => x.Equals(20))) 
{
  Console.WriteLine("yes");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("no");
}
```

output will be `yes` due to `valuesToCheck` contain `20`